# Add host to Docker Container

Tags: docker, ldap, containers, hosts

I am runnig Keycloak on a container with the default image of keycloak. I am trying to add a host to the /etc/hosts file but it is imposible. I want to change the localhost DN to ldap.demo.local
[image: Editing file from Docker Desktop container]

I have also tried to edit the file from the Docker container terminal with vi and nano commands but none of that commands are recognized...

[image: Trying to edit file from de terminal]

What should I do? I need to edit this file...

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: Even though you're talking about running a container and not building the image, the linked question describes the mechanisms Docker has to override DNS like this.  Try to avoid changing the container filesystem using `docker exec`, since that manual change will get lost as soon as the container exits.  I'd also try to avoid changing `/etc/hosts` if you can, again since that manual change will need to be repeated in every networking setup.

Comment: In case you want to adjust some extra hosts during startup, you can always use extra_hosts in compose.yml for the service: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#extra_hosts.

(or the cli --add-host alternative).